# Photos duplicating when displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

When I upload photos the third will duplicate and take over first and the third spot. I have no idea why this bug is happening, but I believe it happened after I added the usort code. When I upload picture nr 1, everythings fine, nr 2, all good, but nr 3 and all after will replace the first and the last spot.

```
$files = glob("Opplastetbilder/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

    $image = $files[$i];
    usort($files, function($a, $b) { 
                    return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); 
                    }
        );
    $supported_file = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {

        echo '<div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.$image.'">
                    <img src="'.$image.'" alt="bilde" width="300" height="200">
                </a>
                <div class="desc">
                    <div class="voting_wrapper" id="'.$i.'">';

                echo '<div class="voting_btn">
                            <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes">0</span>

                            </div>
                            <div class="voting_btn">
                                <div class="down_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="down_votes">0</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>';
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

echo '</body></html> ';
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You don't need to set the `$supported_file` every loop iteration, nor do you need to call `usort()` each time either.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to call `usort` before retrieving the specific item. Likely, you're getting the first element, which in a later iteration has moved. There's therefore an element which got moved to the front of the array and is now never selected due to `i = 0` already being passed. It might potentially even be better to move it out of the loop, as it doesn't actually seem to depend on anything happening within.

Thus, just try moving the following line in front of your loop instead of in it:

```
   usort($files, function($a, $b) { 
                return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); 
                }
    );
```

and let us know if the problem persists.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this worked until I saw that it is not sorting the pictures by time anymore.

Comment: PHP Warning:  usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: Did you place it before or after `$files = glob("Opplastetbilder/*.*");`? It sounds like you placed it beforehand. The order should be: define `$files`, sort it, and then the loop.